# body causing large layout shift

Tags: css, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals, cumulative-layout-shift

I have built a custom coded theme for a client of mine and its passing its core web vitals on mobile but not on the desktop version. It seems the main culprit is the body. [Here](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-thgmwriters-com/w1x6oz5etp?form_factor=desktop) is the score.

I ran it through the CLS Debugger [HERE](https://webvitals.dev/cls/zyniGE7MuTHShssm5NY0) and its not picking it up, instead its giving it a good score.

I changed the CSS on the body to this to se if this would make a difference:

```
body {
  font-family: "Mukta", sans-serif;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

However it has not. Does anyone have any other suggestions to get this website passed for me client.
Many thanks. Phillip Dews

Comment: Contact the freelance exchange with such questions. We're volunteers here, and we're not going to fix your site or your client's site, even for a whopping +50. ... With best regards.

Comment: Possible to share a little more info please Phillip? Currently the two links you've shared are broken URLs and the code snippet isn't much to go on.

Comment: There are a bunch of floats that seems to do nothing, except cause the browser to wait for items to load in order to determine the final height of elements (e.g. the quote box) and once the height is established the elements are moved around again because of floats. use common sense CSS for layout and the score will improve.

Answer (score -1):

- remove the `width: 100%`, body is a block element and will use the full width of the screen by default
- avoid `height: 100%` since if the site every expands (for instance because there is less horizontal space) you will get overflow. i suggest using `min-height: 100%` instead
- i see no reason to use `position: relative` and `float: left` on a body element, you might want to remove these

that's all i can say with the information you gave us.